# Settling time of an op-amp integrator

Tags: operational-amplifier, integrator, miller-integrator

I am trying to simulate an op-amp integrator with a high bandwidth op-amp LTC6253. When I apply a 2mv-p2p signal centered at zero voltage, the integrator settles with an exponential voltage envelope centered around -224mV.But the integral of the square waveform settles around -25mV by calculations i.e. $$V_o =-10^6\int1mV dt =-10^3t$$.

So if we start from zero initial conditions, for 50us, which is the on time of op-amp, we reach -50mV and then again go back to zero as shown
[image: Theoretical]

This gives a waveform centered at 25mV.

From the [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/371645/integrator-dc-drift),I know that this happens due to the feedback 25Mohm resistor.I have added this so that the op-amp does not saturate.I did not want to go through the trouble of using a reset circuit , because we would need again to find some way to reset it at particular times.I think feedback Resistance is the usual cure of this DC drift. And it is suggested to use it as large as possible.For clarity my doubts are:

q1) Why do we see this exponential envelope? Does feedback resistor has something to do with it?
q2) Why is the output not centered at -25mV?
q3) Can we improve the response time?

[image: LTSpice Circuit]
[image: Input Wave]
[image: Output]

[image: Zoomed Output]

Comment: The DC gain is 25000 (88 dB).  That means: An input offset auf app. 0.1mV will saturate the opamp.

Comment: Correct, but I cannot see any saturation here, the output is centered at -224mV, not at Vee.Am i missing something?

Comment: What is your problem?  It seems that the system is oscillating....

Comment: No the system is not oscillating. I added a zoomed version of the waveform to clarify.

Comment: q1) If we theoretically integrate the input, it gives a triangular wave centered around -25mV. So why the extra DC offset as in simulation it settles at around 224mV?

Comment: OK - squarewave input and triangle ouput. So - what is the problem?

Comment: q2) It seems that there is a finite response after which the opamp settles, what factors influence it? How can I make it work faster?

Comment: Where did you observe this effect? I do not understand what you mean....it is a clean triangle, is it not? Or do you want a larger signal at the output? Is the DC offset your problem?

Comment: The DC Offset is the problem.I was expecting a DC offset of 25mv, but i am getting a much lower DC offset.

Comment: And why is this a PROBLEM? I all cases, we are happy with a low offset...

Comment: @SambeetPanigrahi That opamp doesn't use bipolar supplies.